# Aggregate function with a subquery

Tags: sql-server, myeclipse

If someone can direct me to a question that answers this question please feel free and I will close this question, but it seems most answers I found were something simple that was not related to my question.

Anyways, my issue is that I want to put a sub-query into an aggregate query. I'v mocked up some pseudo code below to help illustrate what I would like to be able to do. What bothers me is if I perform the query and hard code the information it works fine, but does not work with the query.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(CASE WHEN subtype IN (SELECT subtype FROM subtype_table WHERE     random_limiter='X') THEN mainTable.quantity ELSE 0)
FROM mainTable
GROUP BY mainTable.groupingColumn
```

The above code will give me the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or sub-query.

But if I replace the query with some text (say... subtype IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) it works fine.

Is there any way I can use a query inside of my SUM? If not, what are my other options? I'd prefer to keep this in a single query if possible. Its also worth noting that in my actual query I have multiple sums, and each has different sub-queries.

Comment: The error is caused when the subquery  returns more than 1 result. You could do a count instead.

Comment: @Alfons Won't changing it to count give me the total number, as opposed to the sum? I applogize I put 1 & 0 as the results... What would happen if that was something like mainTable.quantity instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    COUNT(s.subtype)
FROM mainTable m
LEFT JOIN subtype_table s ON m.subtype = s.subtype AND s.random_limiter = 'X'
GROUP BY m.groupingColumn
```

query #2

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    COUNT(s.subtype)
FROM mainTable m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT subtype
    FROM subtype_table
    WHERE random_limiter = 'X'
) s ON m.subtype = s.subtype
GROUP BY m.groupingColumn
```

Comment: I really hope it wasn't that simple and I was just not getting it from the other examples I saw... I'll try this out and accept if it works for me.

Comment: Wouldn't this give unintended results if there can be more than one match in the subtype table?

Comment: I just implemented and found that out. Will attempt with the second one. **Additional** I implemented it, and it seems to be working. I'll have to take a lot longer to verify the results, but this seems to be correct. Thanks for the quick response.